# Proving a function takes a countable amount of values.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Question: If every point is a local maximum point of $f$, prove that $f$ takes on only a countable set of values.

Attempt: I tried attributing to each point $x$, $2$ rational numbers $a_x,b_x$ such that $f(x)$ is the maximum value on $(a_x,b_x)$, and since there are is a countable set of rational numbers, there's only a countable set of such intervals and so a countable set of values of $f(x)$. However, I can't prove that I can make it so $a_x\neq a_y$ or $b_x \neq b_y$ for $x \neq y$, so I can't remove multiplicities and assume the set of all the intervals is countable. This is where I'm stuck and would love some help.

Answer (score 1):

So for each $x\in\Bbb R$, there are $a_x<x<b_x$  such that $f(y)\ge f(x)$ for all $y\in (a_x,b_x)$. By density of $\Bbb Q$, wlog $a_x,b_x\in\Bbb Q$.
If $a_x=a_\xi$ and $b_x=b_\xi$, then $f(y)\ge f(x)$ and $f(y)\ge f(\xi)$ for all $y\in (a_x,b_x)$, so by considereing $y=x$ and $y=\xi$, we find $f(x)\ge f(\xi)$ and $f(\xi)\ge f(x)$, i.e., $f(x)=f(\xi)$. But if $f(x)$ depends only on $\langle a_x,b_x\rangle\in\Bbb Q^2$, $f$ can take only $|\Bbb Q^2|$-many values.